# Is there a rule organizes the relationships between entities

Tags: c#, oop, domain-driven-design

I am wondering the there is a rule that organizes the relationship between entities

for example if a have the following two entities

```
public class Project : IAggregateRoot<long?>, IAccountEntity
{

    protected virtual IList<Phase> Phases { get; set; }

}

public class Phase : IAggregateRoot<long?>, IAccountEntity
{

    public virtual IList<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

    [RequiredAspect]
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

in this example I have a project and **the project has many phases** and at the same time the **phase references the project** and it has many **tasks** and I am wondering if must a phase or task know to which project is related? or must a task know to which phase is related?, or must we specify that the project has many phases if the phase references that project.

Comment: If you don't know whether a `Phase` needs to know to which `Project` it belongs, we cannot tell you. A `Task`, given that it's a child of `Phase`, on the other hand, doesn't need to know directly (since it can know through the `Phase` relationship)

Comment: This all depends on your business requirements. If you have no business requirements given to you, then you need to make them up based on the problem you are trying to solve. There is no one correct way to do this. It all depends on the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your objects' goals. Generally, it's better to avoid bidirectional relationships in your objects. It increases complexity and their initialization becomes difficult. Objects should encapsulate only the most necessary data/state and should focus on the system's actions and behavior. Think of how a Task or Phase behave and this will define if they need one another.

It's, on the other hand, a perfect and more elegant fit to describe/embed/enforce such rules and data relationships in your database or in your diagrams and schemas (xml/json schemas) using for example sql foreign key constraints and xsd documents. This would also make your data self-documented and application-independent.